# How to prevent latexmk from deleting .aux files pre-build?

Tags: auxiliary-files, latexmk

I have a non-standard build process that I have successfully used a few years ago. It boils down to this:

- I've got a .bib file that contains entries with URLs.
- I'm using `xelatex` to process a file called `QR-Codes.tex`. This basically contains `\nocite{*}` followed by `\printbibliography`, with some code in the preamble to generate a separate page for each entry that contains a QR code generated with using `pst-barcode`. These pages are labeled in the process.
- The main file uses the package `xr` to import the labels from `QR-Codes.aux` and then -- using a combination of `\includegraphics` and `\getpagerefnumber` -- places the correct QR codes in the file wherever requested.

The main file is run through `pdflatex` with the help of `latexmk`. As stated above, I've used this process in 2013/2014 for another project, and it used to work. Now for a similar project with current versions of the tools (Latexmk Version 4.52c), I'm running into the problem that very early after the start of `latexmk`, the file `QR-Codes.aux` is deleted. `latexmk -C -diagnostics` tells me that it determines that the file should be deleted:

```
...
For deletion, the following were determined from fdb file or log file:
 Generated (from makeindex and bibtex):
  mainfile.ilg
  mainfile.idx
  mainfile.blg
  mainfile.ind
 Aux files:
  mainfile.aux
  QR-Codes.aux
  mainfile.bcf
...
```

I've tried to change `@generated_exts` in my `.latexmkrc` as mentioned by the documentation, but that array a) appears to be empty when my `.latexmkrc` file is processed and b) does not change the behavior even when I set it.

The `.latexmkrc` contains the following entries:

```
@default_files = ("mainfile");
$pdf_mode = 1;
$recorder = 1;
$makeindex = "makeindex %O -g -s support/index.ist -t %B.ilg -o %D %S";
add_cus_dep("nlo", "nls", 0, "makegloss");
sub makegloss {
    system("makeindex -g -s support/nomencl.ist -t $_[0].nlg -o $_[0].nls $_[0].nlo");
}
```

So - how do I prevent `latexmk` from deleting an `.aux` file that is used, but not generated by its targets?

Comment: How do you call latexmk? Do you use any options?

Comment: Also, what is in you .latexmkrc file?

Comment: @samcarter: Other than `-diagnostic` at times, I have not used any options.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: see edited question

Comment: @vwegert mmm, which version of latexmk are you using? I have Version 4.52c installed, which does not know `-diagnostic` (and works fine with with aux files and xr)

Comment: @samcarter: Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 19 Jan. 2017, version: 4.52c. - and it was -diagnostics, plural - my bad. It works fine with aux files created by the main file, but in this case it's deleting an aux file that it cannot itself recreate.

Comment: Is QR-Codes.tex being typeset somewhere along the way? I'm not quite understanding how it gets involved here. Have you ever cleaned out all the files and started over?

Comment: @HerbSchulz: Because of compatibility-foo, I need to typeset the QR-Codes.pdf file with xelatex and biber, and after that, I use latexmk to run pdflatex on the main file as often as necessary. All this is held together by a Makefile, but in order to narrow down the question, I've verified that the issue also occurs when I run the commands manually.

Comment: Author of latexmk here: Yes, this is an actual bug which I've reproduced in a simple example. I'll correct it in the next release.  However, I'm surprised you didn't encounter the same problem in 2013/2014: When I did the same test with v. 4.31 (dated 30 Mar 2012) I found exactly the same bug.

Comment: @JohnCollins: Thank you very much. Do you have a timeline for the next release or a suggestion for a workaround, other than re-rendering the QR codes every time (which is quite time-consuming)?

Comment: @vwgert: There's a new version 4.53a for testing at http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8/latexmk/versions.html